# Qt Static build UI low resolution and graphics are off

Tags: qt

I recently did a Qt 5.9.2 Static build using the command

`configure -c++std c++11 -prefix C:\Qt\install -platform win32-msvc2017 -release -opensource -static -static-runtime -no-compile-examples -opengl desktop -nomake examples -nomake tests`

The build works fine, and I'm able to create standalone executables for simple applications. However, when I try to load a QML application, the resolution looks bad and my mouse does not map with the GUI correctly. It seems that the application thinks the mouse is higher than it actually is.

I also receive many errors like this one in my program

`ShaderEffect: Failed to read :/QtQuick/Controls/Shaders/blur.vert`

The program uses a slider and the knobs on it are black boxes.

The programs look and work fine when I switch to my dynamic kit.

I do notice there is a warning saying "No qmlscene installed", could this be related?

How do I fix these issues?

Comment: Do you have highdpi screen? Are you using Qt Quick Controls v2? If yes, have you enabled HighDPI screens support before instantiating QApplication? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-highdpi.html

Comment: Just try to put `QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);` on start of your `main` C++ function app entry point

Comment: > ShaderEffect: Failed to read :/QtQuick/Controls/Shaders/blur.vert  
Might be related to following http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#Q_INIT_RESOURCE ( qrc resources are not linked to static lib and linkage should be forced )

Comment: @MaxGo unfortunately this did not work. I am using both `QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);` and `QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseSoftwareOpenGL);` before my QGuiApplcation is created. If I use the application on a computer with a dedicated GPU, it looks fine. What else can I try?

Comment: And in regards to the ShaderEffect, I think the issue is that Qt is trying to look for the shaders in the QRC, when they are part of the library. I solved this issue by copying the shaders to my program and a QRC file with the specified path. It's kind of annoying, but it will work for the time being.

Comment: Have you tried to set QT_SCALE_FACTOR manually instead of using automatic scaling? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html#high-dpi-support-in-qt

Comment: Yeah, I used `qputenv("QT_SCALE_FACTOR", "1");` and it changes the scale but it's still poorly rendered. I think it's an issue with the kit, considering the fact that it works with the dynamic kits. I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: Do you build this using qmake or cmake? I’d guess it’s missing plugins which contain the shaders…

Comment: I used qmake. I'm not entirely sure how to diagnose to see if something is missing. For the time being I just copied them into a qrc and it works.